# CMake can't see source file, can't find #includes

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion

My first attempt to use CLion (Mac) and CMake. 
My project root folder is `/ref`. It is marked as sources root. 
All source code folders inside `/ref` are marked as library root except `/ref/src`, where my `main.c` resides.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(miniFEPosit)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES /src/main.cpp)            # Add main.cpp file of project root directory
add_executable(miniFEPosit ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I try to build, CLion says "Cannot find source file: `/src/main.cpp`". I get the same message if I try just `main.cpp`.

Also, in the `main.cpp` file, all the `#include` statements say "cannot find" the reference—even obvious ones like `#include <iostream>`.

Separately, can anyone recommend a good place to learn about CMake?

Comment: maybe `/src/main.cpp` path is supposed to be relative path `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR }/src/main.cpp`

Comment: That seems to have fixed the "can't find main.cpp" issue (thanks!) but it still can't find my #includes.

Comment: See [](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)

Comment: Adding the `include_directories( )` line fixed that. I still have other problems but this is huge progress. (I would have thought that marking those directories as "library root" in CLion might have taken care of this, but evidently not. What DOES it do?)

Comment: clion itself does not do much, it does not offer build system or compiler. setting up cmake build scripts (which is far from trivial) is always up to developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised `CMakeLists.txt` file that fixed the issues:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)         # CMake version check
project(miniFEPosit)                        # Create project 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)                  # Enable c++11 standard

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)              # Add src/main.cpp file of project root directory as source file

include_directories(basic fem posit utils)  # subdirectories of project root /ref 

add_executable(miniFEPosit ${SOURCE_FILES}) # Add executable target
```

The key to finding `main.cpp` was eliminating the slash before `src/main.cpp`, which evidently causes it to expect an absolute path. And marking directories as "library root" in CLion doesn't cause them to be searched; you must have an `include_directories(...)` command. (The [CLion documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/controlling-source-library-and-exclude-directories.html#d31863e31) seems to indicate that marking a directory as `library root` should work, but perhaps CMake and the `CMakeLists.txt` file override this feature—any insight appreciated.)

Answer (score 2):

Change `/src` to just `src`. The '/' makes it look for the file directory on the root dir.

```
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
```

Regarding the include files you need to add a `include_directories()` clause containing your project directories that contain needed header files. This lets cmake to provide them correctly to `make` and to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, that worked too, and it also fixed some of the #includes (it seems to be getting the standard ones, and the ones in the `src` folder, but not the ones in my other source folders marked as "library root") Is it permissible to have more than one of these? CLion didn't object.

Comment: As noted in my reply to the earlier commenter, I needed to add `include_directories()` to `CMakeLists.txt`. This fixed the missing #includes.

Comment: My revised `CMakeLists.txt` file: make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)   # CMake version check
project(miniFEPosit)               # Create project "simple_example"
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)            # Enable c++11 standard

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)            # Add main.cpp file of project root directory as source file

include_directories(basic fem posit utils)  # try this--works

add_executable(miniFEPosit ${SOURCE_FILES})       # Add executable target w

Comment: Just add your revised `CMakeLists.txt` as your own answer. Adding proper comments. It may be useful for other people.